# Is a memory barrier required if a second thread waits for termination of the first one?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, multiprocessing, memory-barriers

Suppose that thread `Alpha` is writing to variable `A` without locking. A second thread `Beta` is waiting for `Alpha` to terminate, then reads the variable `A` in turn.

Is it possible that the contents of `A` will not be fresh? Can memory writes be delayed beyond the thread lifetime? Won't the standard mechanism of waiting for thread `Alpha` termination implicitly work as a memory barrier?

**UPDATE 1**

Are there any examples of waiting which does not include a memory barrier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost certainly (the API used to wait for thread termination would need to use memory barriers for its own purposes), but I think for a definitive answer you'll need to talk about the specific threading API being used.

For example, posix makes such a guarantee for `pthread_join()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3208140/12711

And Win32 documents that it's synchronization APIs to wait on an object (for example, a thread handle) impose memory barriers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686355.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what guarantees your threading library provides. In particular, pthread_join() is [defined to be a memory barrier](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_10). In most cases thread joining will involve a memory barrier, but it is not inconceivable that this may not always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

*(Assuming you’re referring to C#.)*

If you mean `Thread` literally, then your answer depends on whether `Thread.Join` implicitly generates memory barriers (which, per the answers already given, it probably does).

However, if you mean that `Alpha` and `Beta` are user-defined tasks executed on a background thread (possibly from the thread pool), and that “waiting” refers to user-level synchronization between the two *tasks*, then it’s more likely that the data will *not* be fresh, unless a signaling construct or an explicit barrier is introduced.

Here is a trivial example:

```
public class Program
{
    static string A = "foo";
    static volatile bool isAlphaReady = false;

    static void Alpha()
    {
        A = "bar";
        isAlphaReady = true;
    }

    static void Beta()
    {
        while (!isAlphaReady)
            ;   // Wait by polling
        Console.WriteLine(A);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(Alpha).Start();
        new Thread(Beta).Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Although it appears (intuitively) that `Beta` will always output `"bar"` as the value of `A`, this is not guaranteed on a multiprocessor system with weak synchronization behaviour (such as Itanium), in which case, `"foo"` may be output instead.

Comment: I don't think the example works in this case. I thought that the CLR ensures a write followed by a write is never swapped.